# Show time on Gremlin Console

Tags: time, console, gremlin

I am trying to measure time taken by a query in Gremlin console. Is it possible to show time with every gremlin prompt? Something similar to how "SET TIME ON" used to work with SQL console for Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that will show the time for every prompt execution. You can of course time a traversal and get information about how it is executing internally with the `profile()` and `explain()` steps:

```
gremlin> g.V().out().profile()
==>Traversal Metrics
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
=============================================================================================================
TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[])                                             6           6          12.308    88.82
VertexStep(OUT,vertex)                                                 6           6           1.268     9.15
NoOpBarrierStep(2500)                                                  6           4           0.281     2.03
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -          13.857        -
gremlin> g.V().out().explain()
==>Traversal Explanation
=======================================================================================
Original Traversal                 [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]

ConnectiveStrategy           [D]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
IncidentToAdjacentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
MatchPredicateStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
FilterRankingStrategy        [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
InlineFilterStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
AdjacentToIncidentStrategy   [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
RepeatUnrollStrategy         [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
CountStrategy                [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
PathRetractionStrategy       [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
LazyBarrierStrategy          [O]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
TinkerGraphCountStrategy     [P]   [GraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
TinkerGraphStepStrategy      [P]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
ProfileStrategy              [F]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
StandardVerificationStrategy [V]   [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]

Final Traversal                    [TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[]), VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
```